# Test status not set on saucelabs

Tags: java, ssl, remote-access, saucelabs

I am writing test to run on sauce-labs. The test is working perfectly on sauce-labs but its doesn't set status for the test(pass/fail). What would be the reason for it ?

```
public class AndroidSauceTest
{
    private SauceOnDemandAuthentication authentication = new SauceOnDemandAuthentication(
            "username", "apikey");
    private SauceREST client = new SauceREST(authentication.getUsername(), authentication.getAccessKey());
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String sessionId;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(Method method) throws Exception
     {

    DesiredCapabilities  caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                new URL("http://" + authentication.getUsername() + ":" + authentication.getAccessKey() + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
                caps);

    this.sessionId = (((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId()).toString();

    }

    @Test(enabled = false)
    public void androidExampleTest() throws Exception {
        try
        {

          //code block
            client.jobPassed(this.sessionId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            client.jobFailed(this.sessionId);
            throw e;
        }
}

   @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Am getting the following error while the running the test. Test status(pass/fail) is not updated on saucelabs. Error shows on this line

```
client.jobPassed(this.sessionId);


3 Feb, 2015 4:34:33 PM com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST updateJobInfo
WARNING: Error updating Sauce Results
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:902)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1235)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1219)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:979)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.updateJobInfo(SauceREST.java:318)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.jobPassed(SauceREST.java:131)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:883)
    ... 23 more
3 Feb, 2015 4:34:34 PM com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST updateJobInfo
WARNING: Error closing result stream
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:902)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1235)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1219)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.updateJobInfo(SauceREST.java:325)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.jobPassed(SauceREST.java:131)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:883)
    ... 23 more
3 Feb, 2015 4:35:41 PM com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST updateJobInfo
WARNING: Error updating Sauce Results
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:902)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1235)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1219)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:979)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.updateJobInfo(SauceREST.java:318)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.jobPassed(SauceREST.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:883)
    ... 23 more
3 Feb, 2015 4:35:42 PM com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST updateJobInfo
WARNING: Error closing result stream
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:902)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1235)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1219)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.updateJobInfo(SauceREST.java:325)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.jobPassed(SauceREST.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:883)
    ... 23 more
3 Feb, 2015 4:37:09 PM com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST updateJobInfo
WARNING: Error updating Sauce Results
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:902)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1235)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1219)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:979)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.updateJobInfo(SauceREST.java:318)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.jobPassed(SauceREST.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:883)
    ... 23 more
3 Feb, 2015 4:37:10 PM com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST updateJobInfo
WARNING: Error closing result stream
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:902)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1235)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1219)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.updateJobInfo(SauceREST.java:325)
    at com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST.jobPassed(SauceREST.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:883)
    ... 23 more
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 233.156 sec
```

Comment: try to set some proxy in your code

Answer (score 0):

Call to update Job should be last activity in your code. Try to update job status in AfterTest/AfterSuite method.

Comment: This should be a comment &  does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).